# Getting an error saying the conversion of a varchar data type to datetime resulted in an out of range value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this sql statement

```
select ord_type,
       case 
            when entered_dt  between '2013-02-01' and '2013-02-31' then 1 
       end  
from oehdrhst_sql
```

I keep getting this error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Whats wrong with it... I can't seem to find a solution

Comment: What Datatype is entered_dt

Comment: datetime     .............

Comment: 31st of February ?!?!?!?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  ord_type
      , CASE WHEN entered_dt  BETWEEN '20130201' AND '20130228' --<-- There are only 28 days in Feb 
             THEN 1 ELSE NULL END  
FROM oehdrhst_sql
```

Comment: I have no clue who would downvote this - this answer is **perfectly valid** and highlights the two main issues - not using the proper **ISO-8601** string-based date format, and not respecting the fact that February 2013 has only 28 days ....

Comment: I guess there are some people here to just down vote because they can :S .

Answer (score 2):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.